# Changing a function variable in a seperate Python script when it is imported

Tags: python

I have the following code inside of a file called my_python_script-

```
def write_output(timestamp, name, alias, key, value, component, source, env):
    """ This is generic Function to write the output of the other scripts"""

    metrics_file = "/opt/reporting/data/metrics"
    data = "writing some stuff"
    with open(metrics_file, "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(data)
```

When I do `import my_python_script`, I can successfully call the function from a separate script after I've imported it.

Is there a way to make it so that I can change the value of "metrics_file" in the second script that I am importing my_python_script into?  I am trying to make it so that I can just overwrite the metrics_file variable and continue to use the same function?

Thanks.

Comment: how about make the `metrics_file` var as another argument of the function ?

Comment: Why don't you make it a parameter of the `write_output` function?

Comment: There are already a pretty wide assortment of scripts using this function, so adding it as a parameter would make it so that I would have to change every function call in all of our scripts (unless there is a way to make the parameter "optional")

Comment: make a    metrics_file as a function parameter

Comment: Nope, that's impossible unless you make `metrics_file` that function's argument.

Comment: you can make the parameter optional with `def write_output(timestamp, name, alias, key, value, component, source, env, metrics_file = "/opt/reporting/data/metrics"):` , it will default to "/opt/reporting/data/metrics"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to make the filename an optional parameter:

```
def write_output(timestamp, namename, alias, key, value, component, source,
                 env, metrics_file="/opt/reporting/data/metrics"):
```

This will by default use the same filename as you have before but also allows you to call it with a different filename.